# Start paragraph with a capital letter and end with a punctuation

Tags: regex

I want to ensure that a user starts a paragraph with a capital letter and ends the paragraph with a punctuation mark (.!?") The paragraph can consist of multiple sentences.

Similarly, I want the option to ensure there is no punctuation mark at the end - this is for a different area.

I have been able to do it for a single sentence with a full stop, but that doesn't pass for multiple sentences:

```
^[A-Z][^\.]*\.$
```

**A sample paragraph:**

> This is a test! I would like to ensure the first character is a
>   capital and the last is a punctuation with anything in between.

Any ideas? I'm new to regex and any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Try `^[A-Z][\s\S]*?\.(?:\n\n|$)` with multiline option on. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKfQlf/1).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! This one worked! I added support to end with ! and ?, but otherwise the same. Can you add it as an answer so can mark it as correct?
`^[A-Z][\s\S]*?\+?[.?!](?:\n\n|$)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
^[A-Z][\s\S]*?[.!?](?:\n\n|\z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKfQlf/3). Make sure you have the multiline option ON so that `^` could match line start positions.

If your line breaks are CRLF, use `\r\n` instead of `\n`, or if your regex supports `\R`, use `\R`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `[.!?]` - final punctuation, `.`, `?` or `!`
- `(?:\n\n|\z)` - either double newline or end of a string.

A PHP regex variation:

```
'~^[A-Z].*?[.!?](?:\n\n|\z)~sm'
```

Or a Unicode supporting one:

```
'~^\p{Lu}.*?[.!?](?:\R\R|\z)~smu'
```