# Regular expression for sentences in the text

Tags: c#, regex

I have the text

```
First question.
1)a 2)b 3)c
Second question.
1)10 2)1 3)0
```

I need the regular expression, that find only questions.

**Each question starts with a capital letter and ends with a dot**, so I tried this - `@"\w(.+)."`, but it won't work

Comment: [I think you can find the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53209736/14854744)

Comment: You need to escape the dot to match a literal dot, try [`(?m)^\p{Lu}(.*)\.`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%5cp%7bLu%7d%28.*%29%5c.&i=First+question.%0d%0a1%29a+2%29b+3%29c%0d%0aSecond+question.%0d%0a1%2910+2%291+3%290) where I further used `\p{Lu}` to match a capital letter and `(?m)` for making the `^` caret match line-start.